# dia export to html

Tags: html, svg, png, dia

Is there any way that I can export dia diagram into html (I know that dia exports to various formats such as svg, pdf, ... but I could not find anything that would allow me to export dia to html (with shapes being individual pictures)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With modern browsers, you can embed SVG in HTML. This will give you shapes as indidual objects. 
With the upcoming Dia 0.98 your SVG could even include hyperlinks:

http://www.dia-installer.de/images/linktest.svg

Note that "shapes being individual pictures" would most likely involve overlapping pictures - is that what you're looking for?